# get_posts empty when called via Ajax

Tags: ajax, get-posts

What would cause a basic `get_posts()` query to return an empty array during an Ajax function?

I have a front end page which loads a form. There is a dropdown which is populated when the page loads with some post titles. The same function that populates the select list values is called via Ajax when the value of another select list changes.

When the function is called via Ajax, the result is an empty array. When the page loads, the select list is fully populated.

By using`error_log( var_export( $args, true ), 0 );` I have confirmed that the arguments passed to the function are the same on both page load and Ajax call and with `error_log( var_export( $addons, true ), 0 );` I confirmed results on page load and an empty array on Ajax call. This also confirms execution of the correct function via Ajax.

```
/**
 * Retrieve all addons.
 *
 * @since   1.4
 * @param   arr         $args   Array of arguments. See @get_posts.
 * @return  arr|bool    Addons.
 */
function mh_get_addons( $args = array() )   {

    $defaults = array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'orderby'        => 'post_title',
        'order'          => 'DESC',
        'post_type'      => 'mh-addon',
        'post_status'    => 'publish'
    );

    $args = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );
    error_log( var_export( $args, true ), 0 );
    $addons = get_posts( $args );
    error_log( var_export( $addons, true ), 0 );
    return apply_filters( 'mh_get_addons', $addons );

} // mh_get_addons
```

Here is the Ajax function. As you can see I am passing no args here whilst testing so I would expect to see the same results I do on the initial page load.

```
function mh_update_form_addon_options() {

    $addons = mh_get_addons();

    if ( ! empty( $addons ) )   {
        $result['type']   = 'success';
        $result['addons'] = $addons;
    } else  {
        $result['type']   = 'success';
        $result['addons'] = 'No addons';
    }

    echo json_encode( $result );

    die();
} // mh_update_form_addon_options
add_action( 'wp_ajax_mh_update_form_addon_options', 'mh_update_form_addon_options' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_mh_update_form_addon_options', 'mh_update_form_addon_options' );
```

`

**UPDATE**
The function is now returning results via the Ajax call when a user is logged in. However, if not logged in, no results. Strange thing is that the initial call to the `mh_get_addons()` function which is initiated on page load *without* ajax returns results regardless of whether or not a user is logged in...

Comment: Where exactly (theme/ plugin + hook) did you add and include this call? Sounds you are too early. Also please do a `var_dump( __FUNCTION__ );` at the beginning of the callback to check if anything at all happens – check the console for output.

Comment: Sorry @kaiser which call/include are you referring to?

Comment: This process is in an extension of another plugin. The core plugin registers the post type within the `init` hook.
The extension's class is instantiated with the `plugins_loaded` hook.
The page displayed is via a shortcode using `add_shortcode`. The shortcode instantiate's a further class within which a method is called and in that method I am using `wp_enqueue_script()` and `wp_localize_script()` for the JS file. The JS file waits for a change to be triggered on a form input field and then processes the call to ajax. I am seeing _No Addons_ as the return

Comment: If you make the ajax call return a hardcoded string does it always return that hardcoded string?

Comment: @TomJNowell - Yes. If my Ajax function simply contains `echo json_encode( array( 'type' => 'success', 'addons' => 'Testing' ) ); die();` _Testing_ is returned.

Additionally, per the `mh_update_form_addon_options()` function above, I get _No Addons_ if the `get_posts()` result is empty

Comment: Then I would treat your `mh_addons` filter with extreme suspicion, eliminate it and simplify as far as you can until it works, and only then start readding in such things as filters etc

Answer (score 1):

To get data from AJAX call you have to `echo` or `print` it. In WordPress you should use [`wp_send_json()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_send_json) function to send data as response to call.

```
function mh_get_addons( $args = array() )   {

    $defaults = array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'orderby'        => 'post_title',
        'order'          => 'DESC',
        'post_type'      => 'mh-addon',
        'post_status'    => 'publish'
    );

    $args = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );
    $addons = get_posts( $args );
    wp_send_json( apply_filters( 'mh_get_addons', $addons ) );

} // mh_get_addons
```

Comment: The function I have attached to the Ajax call handles that side of things. It calls the `mh_get_addons()` function and process the results. (when there are some!)

The problem here is not that the data is not being returned, it is that the get_posts call is empty.

Adding `error_log( var_export( $addons, true ), 0 ); // Confirms no results with Ajax, but results on initial load

Comment: Try to remove `wp_parse_args` line and use `$defaults` in `get_posts` function. Does it change anything?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Also confirmed $args is the same whether using Ajax or not

Comment: Add this into your theme `function.php` file: `add_action('wp_ajax_test', function() { wp_send_json(get_posts()); });` and go to address `http://yourwebpage.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=test`. Does it show something?

Comment: Just a 0 (zero)

Comment: Do you have any posts on your website? It's weird because on clean WP install it returns JSON encoded posts

Comment: Custom post types, yes. I know Ajax is working as I can send to the debug log from within the Ajax function. It's the `mh_get_addons()` which does not work when called from Ajax (I know it is being called as again I can send to debug during Ajax). If the same function is called outside of Ajax it works and returns the 5 results I expect to see.
I have also tested whilst logged in and whilst logged out. Same result.

Comment: To which hook did you register your post types? It should be hooked to `init`. I have no more ideas what could be wrong

Comment: Correct, with a priority of 1.

OK, thanks for your suggestions

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the WP AJAX API, have you tried registering a REST endpoint? This assumes at least WP 4.5:

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route( 'mike/v1', '/addons/', array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'mh_update_form_addon_options',
    ) );
} );


function mh_update_form_addon_options( WP_REST_Request $data ) {

    $defaults = array(
        'posts_per_page'   => 200,
        'orderby'          => 'post_title',
        'order'            => 'DESC',
        'post_type'        => 'mh-addon',
        'post_status'      => 'publish',
        'suppress_filters' => false
    );

    $addons = get_posts( $args );
    $result = array();    
    if ( empty( $addons ) )   {
        return new WP_Error("No addons");
    }

    return $addons;
}
```

I've also simplified the function and eliminated some uncertainty by removing filters. I've also sped up the get_posts call by setting `suppress_filters` to false so that it caches the result. I've also added a maximum number, if you somehow ended up with 1 million addons this request would always fail, so always set an upper limit, even if it's a silly number you know it'll never reach

Keep in mind in a REST endpoint, we return what we're sending, we don't echo it, and use `WP_Error` for problems. You can adjust the `register_rest_route` call to mention arguments, see the WP API documentation for how.

Only WP Core is needed for this, no WP API plugin necessary

Comment: Actually right in the middle of registering API endpoints for all the custom post types the plugin creates so will give that a go

Comment: In this day and age the WP AJAX api should be considered legacy, REST API endpoints are faster and more modern

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling the global `$post` object at the top of your `mh_get_addons()` function?

```
function mh_get_addons( $args = array() )   {

  global $post;

  $defaults = array(
      'posts_per_page' => -1,
      'orderby'        => 'post_title',
      'order'          => 'DESC',
      'post_type'      => 'mh-addon',
      'post_status'    => 'publish'
  );

  $args = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );
  error_log( var_export( $args, true ), 0 );
  $addons = get_posts( $args );
  error_log( var_export( $addons, true ), 0 );
  return apply_filters( 'mh_get_addons', $addons );

  }
```

I'm not quite the wordpress expert yet, but had a similar issue when using `get_posts($args)` inside a function called via wp-ajax the way you call yours, and that solved it for me. Otherwise `get_posts()` wasn't able to retrieve any of the post information, hence the empty array you're seeing.